# Variable Lengths Differ Error

Tags: r

Throughout my function I have arguments `z` and `y`

I want `z` to be equal to a data set (for example `birthwt`) and `y` to be equal to a response variable (for example `birthwt$low`)

```
library("MASS")
library("dplyr")
data(birthwt)

foo=function(z,y){
  n.folds <- 10
  folds <- cut(sample(seq_len(nrow(z))),  breaks=n.folds, labels=FALSE)
  all.confusion.tables <- list()
  for (i in seq_len(n.folds)) {
    train <- filter(z, folds != i) 
    test <- filter(z, folds == i) 
    glm.train <- glm(y ~.,family = binomial, data =  train)
    mod_pred_probs =predict(glm.train,test, type= "response")
    pred.class <- ifelse(mod_pred_probs< 0, 0, 1)
   all.confusion.tables[[i]] <- table(pred = pred.class, true = test$y)
  }
  misclassrisk <- function(x) { (sum(x) - sum(diag(x)))/sum(x) }
  risk <- sapply(all.confusion.tables, misclassrisk)
  return(table(risk))
  mean(risk)}
```

When I run foo(birtht,"low")

I get the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ ., data = train, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'low')
```

Does any one know why I am getting the error or how I can avoid it?

Comment: you probably want to specify y as a string (`"low"` rather than `low`); then use `[[` for indexing and `reformulate` for your formula.

Comment: Hmm I know this is a completely different question but when I run it with (birthwt, "low") I am getting the error "Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ ., data = train, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'low') " what would the reason for this be?

Comment: I think you want `lm(reformulate(".",response=y),...)`

Comment: Is there a particular place I should input that into the formula? I tried it but I ams till getting the same error.

Comment: the result of `reformulate` *is* your formula.  Try it out at the prompt and see how it works ...

Comment: I am getting "Error: '...' used in an incorrect context" as an error.

Comment: the `...` there is not meant to be taken literally; it means "fill in any more arguments that should be here"